# Trees Are Blurry in My Render (Cycles Blender 2.93)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, particles

I am using Blender 2.93 on Windows 10 and Cycles GPU on Experimental Settings.
I did a render that looks like this.
[image]

This is what the trees look like in solid view.
[image]

Why am I getting this blur in the render? Is there something wrong with my settings? I posted pictures of my settings below. Btw I added these trees to the landscape with a particle system based on a collections of trees from Max Tree.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show you show us your camera settings as well? Maybe you turned on depth of field

Comment: Do you use any kind of denoising?

Comment: P.S: If you figure out, which settings led to this effect, please share them. I think it would be a nice touch for nightmarish or surrealistic scenes :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by turning "Render" in the "Sampling" dropdown up to 1024. It took wayyyy longer to render but it worked perfectly and without any artifacts.